# Calculate $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus

Please help me to calculate the $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}$$.

My attemp is:
$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}+\sqrt{1+3x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}+\sqrt{1+3x}}$, but I do not know if I did well, can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}=\dfrac p{x-1}-\dfrac q{x-1}$$

where $\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-2=p\implies x-1=?$

and $\sqrt{1+3x}-2=q,x-1=?$

Answer (score 2):

Since $f^\prime(1):=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$, we have$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-2}{x-1}=\left.\frac73(1+7x)^{-2/3}\right|_{x=1}=\frac{7}{12},$$and similarly $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{x-1}=\frac34$, so your limit is $-\frac16$.

Answer (score 1):

Let change $x=1+u$ with $u\to 0$ then expand $(1+\alpha u)^\beta=1+\alpha\beta\, u+o(u)$

First order is enough for this limit:

$\require{cancel}
\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}=
\dfrac{(8+7u)^\frac 13-(4+3u)^\frac 12}u=
\dfrac 2u\left((1+\frac 78u)^\frac 13-(1+\frac 34u)^\frac 12\right)=
\dfrac 2u\left(\cancel{1}+\frac 7{24}u+o(u)-\cancel{1}-\frac 38u+o(u)\right)=-\dfrac 16+o(1)\to-\dfrac 16$

Answer (score 1):

Just use  the definition of the derivative:
$$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}=\underset{\substack{\downarrow\\\bigl(\sqrt[3]{1+7^{\vphantom{l}}x}\bigr)'_{x=1}}}{\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}'\Bigl|_{x=1}-2}{x-1}}{}-\underset{\substack{\downarrow\\\bigl(\sqrt{1+3^{\vphantom{l}}x}\bigr)'_{x=1}}}{\frac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{x-1}}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

A little overkill but. You can use solving limits by substituions in here.
$$\begin{align}L &=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}\\ &= \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}-\sqrt{1+3x}}{x-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}+\sqrt{1+3x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+7x}+\sqrt{1+3x}}\\&= \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\left(1+7x\right)^{2}}-\left(1+3x\right)}{\left(x-1\right)}\end{align}$$

Take:
$$x=\frac{u^3-1}{7}$$
$$\text{As }x \rightarrow1 \text{, } u \rightarrow 2 $$
Then,
$$\begin{align}L&=-\frac{1}{4}\lim_{u \rightarrow 2} \frac{3u^{3}-7u^{2}+4}{u^{3}-8}\end{align}$$

We got a $P(x)/Q(x)$ form which you solve by removing the factors or by using L'Hopitals